# Add bootstrap panel style like twitter messages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a message with bootstrap to I would like  something like it

**Image example:**

[image]

Here is what I tried so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.limestone.edu/sites/default/files/user.png" width="40px;" height="40px;"  class="img-responsive img-circle" />
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">message here</div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The question is how to get a bootstrap panel style like the image example and also align the user picture to the panel ?

Comment: You need a _moon_ shape that is partially hidden, and here is how to make a _moon_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803334/css3-moon-shape ... by simply use a pseudo, you can easily get that style for your message fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

**Edited to show user image closer**

```css
#curvedarrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(25deg);
}
#curvedarrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 1px 3px 17px 0px;
    top: 12px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}
#img-block{
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#message-block{
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 65px);
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div id="img-block">
  <img src="http://www.limestone.edu/sites/default/files/user.png" width="40px;" height="40px;"  class="img-responsive img-circle" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="message-block">
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div id="curvedarrow"></div>
    <div class="panel-heading">message here</div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice, could you make the user image stay better aligned with the message panel? I would like the user image stay closer the message panel.

Comment: I edited the code to be how you wanted in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my basic attempt. I simply used the idea from here: [CSS3 moon shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803334/css3-moon-shape)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.limestone.edu/sites/default/files/user.png" width="40px;" height="40px;"  class="img-responsive img-circle" />          
    <div class="something">
    </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">message here</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.something {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 15px #ddd, inset 0px 15px 1px 1px #ddd;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(-250deg);
}

.panel {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: -25px;
    background: #00728D;
    }
.container * {
  display: inline-block;
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice example, but hot to make the user image to be aligned with the message panel?

Comment: @Developer Fixed ;)